# Insert statement does not happen inside transaction for many to many relation, Spring JPA, Hibernate, Springboot

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I tried my best to get many to many insert statement happened inside database transaction. 
This is the logging message
[image]

The highlighted text tell that select query start inside transaction but not for insert statement that occurred after transaction commit.

My idea is that I wanted every thing about query go inside transaction.

and these are my code in controller, repository and mapping.

controller action method

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = false,rollbackFor = Exception.class,
            isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}role", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void AddUserToRole(@PathVariable int userId,
                            @RequestBody  AddUserToRoleRequest request) {
        roleRepository.getCurrentFlushMode();
        User user = userRepository.getUserById(userId);
        Role role = roleRepository.getRoleById(request.getRoleId());
        role.getUsers().add(user);
        user.getRoles().add(role);
    }
```

RoleRepository

```
@Repository
public class RoleRepository {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(RoleRepository.class);
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void addRole(Role role) {
        entityManager.persist(role);
    }

    public Role getRoleById(long roleId) {
        Role role = entityManager.find(Role.class, roleId);
        return role;
    }

    public void getCurrentFlushMode() {
        log.info(String.format("current flush mode %s", entityManager.getFlushMode()));
    }


}
```

UserRepository

```
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public  void addUser(User user){
        entityManager.persist(user);
    }

    public  User getUserById(long userId){
     User user =   entityManager.find(User.class,userId);
        return  user;
    }

}
```

Role Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY
            //,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,}
    )
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<User> users;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

User Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(
           // cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
             mappedBy = "user",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Post> posts;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users"
            //, cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    private List<Role> roles;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<Post> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

    public void setPosts(List<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public void addRole(Role role) {
        role.getUsers().add(this);
        this.getRoles().add(role);
    }

}
```

If I explicit called enityManager.flush(); this issue insert statement inside transaction as expected. Hower I just don't want to explicit call flush since insert new user or role I don't need to call flush and insert occurred inside transaction begin/commit.

Thank you so much

Comment: It does not happen after the commit. It happens after the commit has been *initiated* by Spring. Committing the transaction makes Hibernate flush before the actual commit, hence the insert query.

Comment: did you try to change transaction isolation?

Comment: @JBNizet but this for simple add user, the insert statement happened inside transaction 

- Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@388accc2]
Hibernate: insert into users (email, name) values (?, ?)
 - Initiating transaction commit
 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@c73c434]

Comment: @lkrnac no, I just want insert statement for many to many insert occurred inside transaction

Comment: The user insert happens before the final flush because Hibernate needs to execute it before. That doesn't mean the last insert is not executed as part of the transaction. There can be multiple flushes in a single transaction.

Comment: Your "flush mode" is set to "COMMIT" which could be the reason for this behavior. You may want to change it to "AUTO" so that you don't have to explicitly call "enityManager.flush()" to issue insert statement inside transaction.